# How to get data from semi broken micro SDXC card?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, data-recovery, sd-card, crash

I used to have a 64GB micro SDXC card in my mobile phone. But last week, after the phone crashed and I had to restart it hard, the SD card was not mounted anymore. The phone tried for 5 minutes but then told me I could safely remove the SD card.

So I put the SD card in the adapter and inserted it into my laptop computer, Windows 7. Nothing happened. Windows recognized the SD card but clicking it led to no reaction.

Then I got out my pen drive Linux with Ubuntu 14.04-1 LTS. And I got some results.
When I inserted the card I got a dialogue telling me that a medium with digital photos had been detected and asked me for further actions. When I selected "open folder" Ubuntu crashed hard (Kernel panic)[image: Kernel Panic screen]

I searched for help and found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53542/how-to-determine-the-filesystem-of-an-unmounted-device.

Here is the output for the commands recommended there:

Fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/dsc1 -l

Disk /dev/sdc1: 63.9 GB, 63863521280 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 60905 cylinders, total 124733440 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Parted:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc1 -l

Model: Generic- xD/SD/M.S. (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 63,9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  63,9GB  63,9GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

File:

```
sudo file -sL /dev/sdc1

/dev/sdc1: x86 boot sector
```

Executing df -T leads to the same crash as above.

I would like to know which programs or commands to use in this situation in order to get at least my photos off the SD card or even better, all files or an image file. If the SD card itself is lost, so be it, I only need the data.

Answer (score 1):

The drm_kms_helper message at the bottom indicates a problem with drm, most probably your video card driver.

To recover lost images on media, you could use photorec and testdisk.